# How to create permutations of a logical vector?

Tags: r

Is there a function that will help me output all 2^n permutations of a boolean vector of length n? For instance, if i have a boolean vector of length n=2, c(FALSE,FALSE), i should obtain 2^2=4 permutations.

As such, I need a function, that will generalize this output for an array of length n,
that means if n=3, output should be of length 2^3 and so on...

I have already tried permutations from gtools package but this seems to be incorrect, or providing only a partial answer to say the least. This method does not generalize well and has given me errors for n>2 as well.

```
> permutations(2,2,c(TRUE,FALSE))
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] FALSE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE
```

Output should be:

```
FALSE, FALSE,
TRUE, TRUE,
FALSE, TRUE,
TRUE, FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where missing `repeats.allowed=T` :

```
gtools::permutations(2,2, c(T,F), repeats.allowed = T)

      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE
```

You can make your custom function around `permutations`:

```
my_permute <- function(vect, n, repeats = TRUE) {

  gtools::permutations(length(vect), n, vect, repeats.allowed = repeats)
}

my_permute(vect=c(T,F), n=2)
```

Example with more elements:

```
my_permute(letters[1:3], n=3)
```

Comment: Thanks, and for n elements, eg.n=3, i use permutations(2,3, c(T,F,T), repeats.allowed = T)

Comment: the first paramenter (2) is the length of the vector. Read more here: https://davetang.org/muse/2013/09/09/combinations-and-permutations-in-r/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expand.grid`,

```
expand.grid(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(TRUE, FALSE))
#   Var1  Var2
#1  TRUE  TRUE
#2 FALSE  TRUE
#3  TRUE FALSE
#4 FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *gtools* package and the function *permutations*:
This is the source code:

```
library(gtools)
x <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
permutations(n=length(x),r=2,v=x,repeats.allowed=T)
```